# Dataprep Bigquery running in different region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dataflow, google-cloud-dataprep

So I get the following error when running dataprep.

```
java.io.IOException: Query job beam_job_9e016180fbb74637b35319c89b6ed6d7_clouddataprepleads6085795bynick-query-d23eb37a1bee4a788e7b16c1de1f92e6 failed, status: { "errorResult" : { "message" : "Not found: Dataset lumi-210601:attribution was not found in location US", "reason" : "notFound" }, "errors" : [ { "message" : "Not found: Dataset lumi-210601:attribution was not found in location US", "reason" : "notFound" } ], "state" : "DONE" }
```

I've tried doing the following already:

1. Under dataprep "Project Settings" I've et the regional endpoint to asia-east1 and the zone to australia-southeast-1a
2. Have set under "Profile" all of the upload/job run dir/temp dir to new directories in a bucket that belongs to the australia south east
3. In the flow output I'm just doing a basic CSV output to test with dataprep execution settings  to be australia region as well

I can't seem to find any other references to US anywhere. If I go into the dataflow UI I can see that the jobs ran and failed on the asia-east region as well

Comment: How is your recipe?  Are trying to read data and save it in a table in another region/project?